# setInterval spamming function

Tags: javascript, image, webstorm, setinterval

I am trying to use the setInterval command to reset the position of a sprite every "x" seconds, but for some reason, after the first time it is called, it spams the command over and over, instead of waiting the desired amount. Here is my javascript code relating to the image drawing & updating:

```
function animate() {

    refresh = requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    background();
    imgs();
    setInterval(function() { newImgCords() }, 1000);

}

function background() {

    var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
    canv.fillStyle = "#c8c8c8";
    canv.fillRect( 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function imgs() {

    var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

    canv.drawImage(face, imgX, imgY, 100, 50);

}

function newImgCords() {

    imgX = Math.random() * (400 - 100) + 100;
    imgY = Math.random() * (400 - 100) + 100;

}
```

I have a video on what happens, but I don't think if I am able to add it to this post. If it would help, please let me know how to link a URL to a video (I'm not sure how, or if I could just add the video in a post) and I will add the video as soon as I can. Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling your animate function only once? Or multiple times?

Comment: The function gets called repeatedly, it is supposed to make a flowing animation.

Comment: Ok, so every time you call animate you are creating a new setinterval. Call setinterval just once, maybe in another function called just once

Comment: I just tried this, the same issue occurs. I called it in a function that activates upon the click of a button, yet it still spams that function. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: The button is only clicked once? Have you removed set interval from animate?

Comment: Yes, I have done that as well. the only place setInterval() is being called is in the button's function, although the problem remains.

Comment: Can you try calling like this setinterval(newimagecords,1000) ?

Comment: The output is the same. I am trying to solve the problem with a different method now, using a timer variable that increases in value, and when greater than a certain amount, will reset the coordinates of the image. Let me check if it works.

Comment: It works! I set a new variable, timer, to 0, and had the value increase in my animate() function (timer++). I called a new function in animate() that checked if the timer was greater than a certain amount, and if so, to reset the coordinates. These will then be redrawn in the imgs() function. Thank you for helping!